# Issue in using scale colour manual in geom bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like:

```
AA  Extracellular   Intracellular
A   2.23        5
B   8.6         5
C   13.5        5
```

Code looks like:

```
rdatamy<-read.table("rat.txt",header=TRUE) # load the File
molten2<-melt(rdatamy,id.vars="AA",measure.vars=c("Extracellular","Intracellular"))#melt
plot2<-ggplot(molten2,aes(x=AA,width=0.3,y=value,colour=variable))+ 
geom_bar(position='dodge',stat="identity") + scale_color_manual(values=c("Intracellular" = 
"cyan","Extracellular" = "gold2"))
```

So, I am plotting a barpolot to compare 2 different things.

The color they get are not the ones, I mention in scale color manual. However, the same color scheme works in geom_point for bubble plot over same variables. If I use `fill=variable` the bars get filled with some different colours. Below is my `geom_point()` code:

```
plot1<-ggplot(molten, aes(x = variable, y = AA, size = value, colour = variable)) + 
geom_point()+scale_color_manual(values=c("Intracellular" = "cyan","Extracellular" = 
"gold2","TM" = "lightpink4"))+ scale_size(range = c(0, 10),name="")
```

Please help me understand this.

Comment: To change colors for bars use `fill=variable` and `scale_fill_manual()` with values you need because `color=variable` will change line around the bar.